# Unable to render Reactjs-boostrap popover

Tags: react-bootstrap, popover

I have the following package installed:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

And I am trying to add a popover using an example provided [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-position-react-bootstrap-popover) example.

This is the exact code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


function App() {
  const popover = (
    <Popover id="popover-basic">
      <Popover.Title as="h3">Popover title</Popover.Title>
      <Popover.Content>
        Popover content <strong>some strong content</strong> Normal content again
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );
  
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={popover}>
      <Button variant="success">Click to trigger popover</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But it just doesn't work. I don't see any errors in the console. And the popover does not render at all. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Maybe try resetting cache, reinstalling, hard refreshing the browser if you haven't already.

Comment: It looks ok https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-snow-msjte?file=/src/App.js post your `package.json` as well

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`. That is mentioned on the doc you suggested too.

From [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-meaning-of-save-for-npm-install/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%93save%2Dexact%20or%20%2DE,npm%27s%20default%20server%20range%20operator.) Article,

```
Before npm 5.0.0, it was necessary to add --save after package name because it 
will save the installed package to package.json file in the dependency section. 
If you are using a recent version of npm save yourself from unnecessary typing 
and use npm install [Package Name] instead of npm install [Package Name] --save 
by default it will add the installed package to the dependency list in the 
package.json file.
```